# CN3722 External MOSFET heating up

Tags: battery-charging, switch-mode-power-supply, charging, powermosfet, solar-charge-controller

In my charging circuit, CN3722 is used as the charging controller where I'm using an external MOSFET FDS4435bz as per it's application. Earlier I was using DMG2307L-7 which was heating up(50°C). To avoid it I changed it to a better specified Mosfet and also a larger package. i.e. FD4435 which is heating up more(70°C and above) than DMG2307.

NOTE: Temperature are measured with thermocouple(FLIR TG267)

As I doubted on the following points;

1. Rds channel is not turning ON properly.
2. CN3722 Controller is not able switch at its operating frequency.
3. Layout issue.

I Checked the Vs= 11.5V. Vgs = 3.7V, Charging voltage = 8.4V(2 cell), Charging current= 810mA, Frequency = 311kHZ(Measured in Multimeter).

MOSFET:

[image]

Overall positions and layouts:

[image]

Should I perform any other tests? Please help me out to find the RCA.

Answer (score 1):

The gate charge of your new larger FET, FDS4435bz, has Qg = 28nC of gate charge, whereas the previous FET, DMG2307L-7 had Qg = 8nC.  This is 3.5x more charge to supply and remove during a switching event.

The equation for current in the gate due to gate charge is shown below.  So it can be seen that your circuit is now pushing/pulling 3.5x more current with the new FET.

\$I_g=\large\frac{Q_g}{t_s}\$

[Anatomy of Gate Charge](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/14697-making-use-of-gate-charge-information-in-mosfet-and-igbt-data-sheets)

Another good source of information is this [TI app note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt664/slyt664.pdf?ts=1649003304711&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F).
The power dissipated in the gate due to switching frequency is:
\$Pgate = Q_g*V_g*F_{sw}\$
Again, it can be seen that the switching power is going to be 3.5 times larger due to the gate charge.

Comment: Today, I added a better spec MOSFET AO4606 to test having better Crss, good Rds_ON and Gate charge is also balanced ~3nC. I used the P-MOS part as it is a dual MOSFET. This is again badly heating up. I checked, it draws current instantly to 1.02A. Set current is 1A but as it is a switch mode charging circuit the charging current gradually rises up to 1A(practically starts from 810mA)